# doctrine2 - delete all onetomany relations

Tags: doctrine-orm, one-to-many

I have following entities

> 1. Professional

```
class Professional extends User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserBundle\Entity\Timeslot", mappedBy="professional", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $timeslots;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->timeslots = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add timeslot
     *
     * @param \UserBundle\Entity\Timeslot $timeslot
     *
     * @return Professional
     */
    public function addTimeslot(\UserBundle\Entity\Timeslot $timeslot)
    {
        $this->timeslots[] = $timeslot;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove timeslot
     *
     * @param \UserBundle\Entity\Timeslot $timeslot
     */
    public function removeTimeslot(\UserBundle\Entity\Timeslot $timeslot)
    {
        $this->timeslots->removeElement($timeslot);
    }

    /**
     * Get timeslots
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getTimeslots()
    {
        return $this->timeslots;
    }

    public function clearTimeslots()
    {
        $this->timeslots->clear();
    }
}
```

> 2. Timeslot Entity

```
class Timeslot
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="day", type="string", length=20, nullable=false)
     */
    private $day;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="starttime", type="time", nullable=true)
     */
    private $startTime;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="endtime", type="time", nullable=true)
     */
    private $endTime;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="available", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    private $available = true;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="UserBundle\Entity\Professional", inversedBy="timeslots", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="professional_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=false, nullable=false)
     */
    private $professional;
}
```

I want to delete all timeslots for a given professional, I tried doing

```
$professional->getTimeslots()->clear();
$em->persist($professional);
$em->flush();
```

This does not delete the data, how do I delete all timeslots for a given professional?

Comment: I recommend a `Repository` function which allows it. In your case you're not *clearing* the *owning side* of the relationship.

Comment: Need a cascade remove on your Professional::timeSlots property. http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations  Cascade stuff can be tricky to say the least.  Having a cascade property on Timeslot::professional makes little sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve this with `->clear()`, but you have to add some code to your `Professional` entity.

```
@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserBundle\Entity\Timeslot", mappedBy="professional", cascade={"merge", "persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
```

1. Adding a cascade="merge"
2. Set orphanRemoval=true

Then in your controller you can just :

```
$professional->getTimeslots()->clear();
$professional = $em->merge($professional);
$em->flush();
```

Hope it helps